# iPhone app flipbook animation crashing on device

Tags: ios, image, memory-management, jpeg

The app uses a series of jpg's and a timer that steps through them to make an animation.

During the animation on the device, it crashes (didReceiveMemoryWarningError.)

I'm new to iPhone programming and Objective-C. How can I optimize this flipbook for the iPhone?

I can imagine simply compressing the jpeg's and perhaps losing some quality would help, but my understanding is the iPhone does its own image compression/decompression on the device and I may be wasting my time.

Comment: you should release all images you have already used. run the Instruments tool for looking for memory leaks or run "Analyze". maybe give a look into some code where you show the images etc.

Comment: I need to run the same animation at least a few times each time the app opens, so can't nil them out easily. Please see my answer and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried different things, eventually hit on storing an array of NSData objects and converting to UIImage on the fly.

```
for (NSString *imageFile in directoryList) {
    NSString *fileLocation = [imageFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFile];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
    if (imageData) {
        [images addObject:imageData];
    } else {
        [Util trace:@"cannot get image data for image named: %@", fileLocation];
    }
```

and then to update your image:

```
 -(void)updateImageView:(id)sender
{       
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[images safeObjectAtIndex:nextImage] ];
    [imageView setImage:anImage];
    nextImage++;
}
```